# Programmatic login using the Android Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I've read through the documentation and source code and other relevant questions here, but I am still having an issue authorizing/logging into my app using the Facebook SDK 3 for Android.

I do not want to use the "Login" button provided.

Here is the relevant code:

On the Activity.onCreate I start the session:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("facebook_storage", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (session == null) {
        if (access_token != null) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
            editor.putString("access_token", null);
            editor.commit();
            AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.createFromExistingAccessToken(access_token, null, null, null, null); 
            session.open(accessToken, this);

        } else {
            session = new Session(getApplicationContext());
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(this));
        } else if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED)) {
            System.out.println("Session created, no token. I guess");
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(this));
        }
    }
```

This triggers:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Which in turn triggers the next block, entering at `if (session.isOpened())`:

```
public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (session == null) {
        MmfLogger.error("FacebookLogin session == null in call()");
    } else if (session.isOpened()) {
        System.out.println("Session.StatusCallback success: " + session.getState());
        Request request = new Request(session, REQUEST_FIELDS, null, null, this);
        request.executeAsync();
    }   
    if (!session.isOpened()) {
        System.out.println("session failed to open");
    }
    if (session.isOpened() && session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
        Request request = new Request(session, REQUEST_FIELDS, null, null, this);
        request.executeAsync();
    } else if (session.isOpened() && session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED)) {
        System.out.println("session isOpened and state is created");
    }

}
```

And from here I get and error stating I need an active token. However, before the Request is made, I can see the token. The session has one. Where am I going wrong?

Thank you for your time.